# Play audio when clicking on a button

Tags: java, android, google-text-to-speech

I would like to simply hear the audio "Hello World", by using Google Text-to-Speech.

This is what I have tried so far (the code is mostly from [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/libraries#using_the_client_library)):

```java
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    try {
        hello();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


/** Demonstrates using the Text-to-Speech API. */
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public void hello() throws Exception {
    // Instantiates a client
    try (TextToSpeechClient textToSpeechClient = TextToSpeechClient.create()) {
        // Set the text input to be synthesized
        SynthesisInput input = SynthesisInput.newBuilder().setText("Hello, World!").build();

        // Build the voice request, select the language code ("en-US") and the ssml voice gender
        // ("neutral")
        VoiceSelectionParams voice =
                VoiceSelectionParams.newBuilder()
                        .setLanguageCode("en-US")
                        .setSsmlGender(SsmlVoiceGender.NEUTRAL)
                        .build();

        // Select the type of audio file you want returned
        AudioConfig audioConfig =
                AudioConfig.newBuilder().setAudioEncoding(AudioEncoding.MP3).build();

        // Perform the text-to-speech request on the text input with the selected voice parameters and
        // audio file type
        SynthesizeSpeechResponse response =
                textToSpeechClient.synthesizeSpeech(input, voice, audioConfig);

        // Get the audio contents from the response
        ByteString audioContents = response.getAudioContent();

        // Write the response to the output file.
        try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("output.mp3")) {
            out.write(audioContents.toByteArray());
            System.out.println("Audio content written to file \"output.mp3\"");
        }
    }
}
```

If I run my app and click on a button, I do not hear anything but also don't get any errors. This is what `e.printStackTrace();` returns:

```
W/System.err: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
W/System.err:     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1450)
W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:102)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:90)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:787)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:175)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:141)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:83)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:174)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:148)
        at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:84)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1012)
        at com.google.auth.oauth2.ComputeEngineCredentials.runningOnComputeEngine(ComputeEngineCredentials.java:237)
W/System.err:     at com.google.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider.tryGetComputeCredentials(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:302)
        at com.google.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider.getDefaultCredentialsUnsynchronized(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:212)
        at com.google.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider.getDefaultCredentials(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:126)
        at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:119)
        at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:91)
        at com.google.api.gax.core.GoogleCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(GoogleCredentialsProvider.java:67)
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:142)
        at com.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1.stub.GrpcTextToSpeechStub.create(GrpcTextToSpeechStub.java:74)
        at com.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1.stub.TextToSpeechStubSettings.createStub(TextToSpeechStubSettings.java:104)
W/System.err:     at com.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1.TextToSpeechClient.<init>(TextToSpeechClient.java:128)
        at com.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1.TextToSpeechClient.create(TextToSpeechClient.java:109)
        at com.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1.TextToSpeechClient.create(TextToSpeechClient.java:101)
        at ch.yourclick.kitt.MainActivity.hello(MainActivity.java:69)
        at ch.yourclick.kitt.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:58)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The log exactly says what you are doing wrong. You need to perform the operation of `hello()` inside a background thread instead of doing it in the main thread.

There are a several ways to run your operations in a background thread. A simple implementation could be the following.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    try {
        Thread ttsThread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                hello();
            }
        };
        ttsThread.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```